# How to roll back changes and display error when an event throws an exception in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

### TL;DR

I would like to know how I should handle an exception that occurs in an event and subsequently rollback changes made to the database prior to the exception, provide feedback to the user and write a test for all of this too.

### Full Details

In my Laravel web application I have four models: `Applicant`, `Application`, `ApplicationAction` and `Document`. An `Applicant` can have one `Application` which can have many `ApplicationAction`s. Also, an `Application` can have many `Document`s.

Conceptually, within the application when an `ApplicationAction` is created it is *applied* to an `Application` which in turn has its `status` attribute updated. For example, if an `ApplicationAction` is of type `reject` the `Application`'s `status` then becomes `rejected`.

Getting into the code where this all happens, I have an `ActionController` with a `store()` method that creates a new `ApplicationAction`:

**ActionController.php**

```
public function store(StoreActionFormRequest $request)
{
    $actionDetails = (new ApplicationAction)->createFromRequest($request);
}
```

**ApplicationAction.php**

```
public function createFromRequest(Request $request)
{
    return $this->create([
        'action'           => $request->action,
        'action_meta'      => $this->actionMeta($request),
        'details'          => $request->details,
        'details_external' => $request->details_external,
        'action_by'        => $request->user()->id,
        'application_id'   => $request->application->id,
    ]);
}
```

On the creation of a new `ApplicationAction` the `ApplicationActionCreated` event is fired with a listener that modifies the `Application`'s `status` attribute based on `ApplicationAction`. I am not including the code in as it's not relevant.

When the `Application` is updated in this process (i.e. its status is changed) an event is triggered: `ApplicationUpdated`. A listener for this event is the `NotifyApplicationWasUpdated` listener which sends an email to the `Applicant`:

**NotifyApplicationWasUpdated.php**

```
/**
 * Handle the event.
 *
 * @param  ApplicationUpdated  $event
 * @return void
 */
public function handle(ApplicationUpdated $event)
{
    if ($mailable = MailableType::resolve($event->application)) { 
        $to = $event->application->applicant->user->email;
        $from = $event->application->applicant->dispatchEmail('verification');

        Mail::to($to)
            ->bcc($from)
            ->send(new $mailable($event->application));
    }
}
```

The mailable is determined dynamically (code not relevant) and within the mailable an attachment is added to the email:

**A dynamically determined MailableClass**

```
/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    //... some code

    $documents = $this->application->documents->whereIn('type', ['some-document', 'some-other-document']);

    $documents->each(function ($document, $key) {
        // TODO: check the file exists first
        $this->attach(storage_path($document->file_path));
    });

    return $this->from($from)->view($view);
}
```

I would like to handle the `FileNotFound` exception if the file to be used as an attachment cannot be found. If this exception occurs then the email would not be sent, so I thought it would be a good idea to rollback the changes made to the database prior to the exception which would include deleting the newly made `ApplicationAction` and returning the `Application`'s `status` to its previous value.

I would also like to provide the user appropriate feedback such as the file intended to be used as an attachment couldn't be found and also that the `ApplicationAction` was not created and the `Application` status was not modified.

The approaches I have considered to handling the `FileNotFound` exception in the event that the `Document` cannot be found when executing this line of code `$this->attach(storage_path($document->file_path));` is to check if the file exists first and if it doesn't then to rollback changes and respond to user with an error:

```
if(!file_exists(storage_path($document->file_path))) {
    // roll back DB changes and show user error page
    $this->application->rollback(); // some method that sets the status to its previous value, not implemented it yet
    $this->application->lastAction()->delete(); // delete the last action
    // then throw an exception to be handled by Laravel exception handler
    // which in turn responds to user with an appropriate message?
}

$this->attach(storage_path($document->file_path));
```

...but I'm a bit unsure on the details of how to rollback the DB changes and show the error to the user. I could either use the above approach, having a `Application` `rollback()` method etc. or instead wrapping the controller `store()` action in a try-block and `DB::transaction()/commit()`, which would look something like this:

**ActionController.php**

```
public function store(StoreActionFormRequest $request)
{
    DB::beginTransaction();

    try {
        $actionDetails = (new ApplicationAction)->createFromRequest($request);
    } catch(FileNotFoundException $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        throw $e;
    }

    DB::commit();
}
```

Then, as mentioned before, use the Laravel exception handler which in turn responds to user with an appropriate error message:

**Handler.php**

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof FileNotFoundException) {
        return response()->view('errors.file_not_found', [], 500);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

If I did use this approach would it be possible to pass some specific text explaining to the user the email was not sent and why? Would I be better off creating my own EmailAttachmentFileNotFoundException and have it hardcoded in the view and using this in `Handler`s `render()` function?

Finally, I would most importantly like to ask how may I write a test for all the above? As most of the logic I'm trying to implement is around an event, which is currently occuring synchronously, how would I write a test for this specific event/listener because I already have something testing the controller action in the form of an integration test but it all it tests for is if the event is fired. How would I then write an isolated test of a test that goes smoothly, i.e. the email is sent successfully and secondly how would I write a test that goes wrong and check it's handled correctly, i.e. email attachment is not found and `FileNotFound` exception is triggered then check the DB stuff is rolled back and the user gets the correct error page?

Any help would be appreciated and if this question can be made any shorter please feel free to edit away!

Comment: Your question is too long and your TL;DR is insufficient for us lazy bums

Comment: My feeling is that you can't do this. Mailables are send via a queue and once you've queued something you've already passed control of it to the queue manager and away from your application. Things like transactions will not work with exceptions within a mailable. I'd suggest to pre-emptively check the existance of the file before creating the mailable and throwing the exception at that point.

Comment: @apokryfos I agree, I'll try rewrite it - thanks for your input!

Comment: @apokryfos I am currently using Events/Listeners & Mailables synchronously as I was using them to break logic out of the controller not for the queue'd job benefit, so my idea was to respond to the exception immediately. Although this does back me into a corner if I ever decide to begin using queues in the future. The issue I have with a pre-emptive check is that the Mailable is triggered by an Event/Listener which could already be potentially queued. Perhaps I should create a new ApplicationAction or attribute on the action that explains to the admin if the action was completed successfully?

Comment: I think your mistake is in the whole idea that the handler that is meant to handle successful updates can cause said updates to fail. You might need to rethink this.